# Incorrect Output after Function Call

Tags: c++, pointers, output, function-call

I expect the result is undefined or something, but the output is "10",  why?

I suppose the memory is destroyed after the function gets called.

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int *p)
{
    int l = 20;
    int *k = &l;
    p = k;
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *j = &i;
    f(j);
    std::cout << *j;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any compilation warning?

Comment: It's pretty clear that what you meant was `*p = *k;` on the last line of `f()`. Or maybe you just meant `*p = 20;`. In C++ if you want to dereference a pointer you have to do it explicitly with `*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result isn't undefined. You pass the pointer `j` **by value**, so you modify a copy of it inside the function. The original `j` is left unchaged, so the result is still `10`.

Answer (score 1):

The program is well formed as the local variable `l` is *not* accessed outside of `f()` as the pointer `j` is unchanged in `main()` (a copy of the pointer `j` is passed to `f()`).

Answer (score 1):

Lets decompose your code.

You first assign 10 to `i`. Then make `j` point to the adress of `i`.

In f, you set the value of `p`, **and not the value it points to**, to `k`. As passed as a parameter of `f()`, p value is copied (the adress value).

In consequence, you never modify the value pointed by `j`, simply the local value of `j` in `f()`, that is why it stays equal to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code. The parameter of `f` is not passed by reference, so `f` has no way to modify `j`, therefore `j` still points to `i` after `f` exits.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about passing by reference / passing by value. While you are passing a pointer, the pointer itself is a number that you pass to the `f()` function pointing to a chunk of memory; modifying the *p variable in `f()` (rather than the chunk of memory where `*p` points to) will have no effect in the `main()` function.

A pointer is just a variable that holds an address of memory. In itself, it is passed by value; only the variable *to which the pointer points* is passed by reference.